# AngularJS/JSON: Error: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '/' at angular.js:9037

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

So i have a program that's generating a map based on reading from a json file. When I click on the option to draw the map, i get the following error in the Safari browser element inspector:

```
Error: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '/'
```

After combing through the json file and making sure it was correct, I realized there are no '/' tokens anywhere in the file. not even a //(i read about escaping characters). It says the error generates from:

```
angular.js:9037
```

and the contents of that line are:

```
function consoleLog(type) {
      var console = $window.console || {},
          logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop;

      if (logFn.apply) {
        return function() {
          var args = [];
          forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
            args.push(formatError(arg));
          });
          return logFn.apply(console, args); #this is line 9037 in angular.js
        };
      }
```

I'm not familiar with angular.js at all, and I am not understanding why i'm getting this error. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: its still a json parsing error. without looking at json, its hard to tell. But try logging 'console' and 'args' value and see what data  is passing thru.

Comment: I validated using http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html and it says it's valid JSON in javascript and RFC 4627. Any other suggestions?